# How to perform arithmetic operation in foreach java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

I am new to java 8 and I tried to write the below code snippet in java 8 but did work.

```
static int getMissingNo(int a[], int n) { 
    int i, total; 
    total = (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        total -= a[i]; 
    return total;
} 

// this is waht i tried in java 8
int  total = (n+1) * (n+2) /2;
unicArray.stream().forEach(e->{
    total  = total - e;
});
```

The code snippet gives me a compilation error saying local variable should be final but if it is final how can I return that value back

Comment: What is your requirement and usecase?

Comment: the requirement is to return missing number in an integer array.

Comment: if array is int[] a = {1,2,4,5,6} should return 3

Comment: So what is this variable n? and does your iterative implementation work?

Comment: size of the array

Comment: the logic inside the getMissingNo(..) works correct..and same I was trying in java 8 using forEach but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the code below :

```
static List<Integer> getMissingNo(int[] a, int n) {

        List<Integer> listOfDistinctElements = Arrays.stream(a)
                .boxed()
                .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Integer> elemntsLeftOut = new ArrayList<>();

        IntStream.range(1, listOfDistinctElements.get(listOfDistinctElements.size()-1)).forEach(index ->
                        {
                            if(!listOfDistinctElements.contains(index)){
                                 elemntsLeftOut.add(index);
                        }
                    });

        return elemntsLeftOut;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. But how to find multiple missing numbers { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 ,7}; output : 4,6

Comment: Edited it as for multiple missing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the difference between the `total` and the `sum` of array as :

```
int expectedSum = (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2;
int actualSum = Arrays.stream(a).sum();  // .distinct().sum() for sum of unique numbers
return expectedSum - actualSum;
```

Comment: Thanks.works correct if array does not contain duplicaiets and multiple missing numbers.  but does not work if the input is {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7} .

Comment: duplicates can be removed by hashset and i want to iterate using java8 feature through hashset and find missing numbers in hashset<Ineteger>

Comment: @raju you didn't complete the input either, what would be `n` given that you're pointing to duplicates now. Also, the solution with the iterative approach shared in the question wouldn't "work" there.

Comment: Sample if the input is  { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 ,7}  the expected output is 4,6.
 getMissingNo(int a[], int n)  where a is a given array and n is number of elements in an array

Comment: @raju The existing code doesn't really deal with duplicates or multiple missing numbers to be found, that's what the solution was for. On the other hand, the implementation of the method that you wrote or the question that you've posted doesn't really indicate that as an attempt. It might just be a better idea to post that attempt and where you get stuck as a different question.